# PHP foreach bypass false values

Tags: php, foreach

How can i make the code run if one of the values returned from `$latest_cases_images[$value]->getName()` is false ?

```
foreach ($latest_case_id as $key => $value) {
    $latest_case_img[] = $latest_cases_images[$value]->getName();
}

$latest_case_id contains an array of id`s
```

Answer (score 2):

Add condition

```
foreach ($latest_case_id as $key => $value) {
    if( false !=== $latest_cases_images[$value]->getName() )
       $latest_case_img[] = $latest_cases_images[$value]->getName();
}
```

OR

```
foreach ($latest_case_id as $key => $value) {
        if( !empty($latest_cases_images[$value]->getName()) )
           $latest_case_img[] = $latest_cases_images[$value]->getName();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
foreach ($latest_case_id as $key => $value)
{
    if( false === $latest_cases_images[$value]->getName() )
    {
        $latest_case_img[] = $latest_cases_images[$value]->getName();
        break;
    }
}
```

Comment: It is always advisable to add some elaborate explanation to your code

Answer (score 0):

You could do the same and check if `$latest_case_img[]` has a `false` value

```
foreach ($latest_case_id as $key => $value) {
    $latest_case_img[] = $latest_cases_images[$value]->getName();
}
if(in_array(false,$latest_case_img)) {
    //Do something
}
```

See [Php.net](http://php.net/manual/en/function.in-array.php) for `in_array`